Android Quiz game app: can't connect correct answer with clicked choices
I am trying to build a quiz app. I can't connect the correct answer to the choices.
I want the quiz to show a questions with 24 possible answers , and update question and choices even if answer isn't correct.
I am using to fill the recyclerview and adapter:
String[] mQuestions = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.questions);
String[] mChoices = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.choices);
String[] mCorrectAnswers = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.correctanswers);
My question is: How can I identify the correct answer and shuffle correctly?
public class QuizRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<QuizRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private Button questions;
private Button score;
private String[] mQuestions;
private String[] mChoices;
private String[] mCorrectAnswers;
private String correctanswer;
private int mScore;

public QuizRecyclerAdapter(Context context, Button questions, Button score, String[] mQuestions, String[] mChoices, String[] mCorrectAnswers) {
    this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.questions = questions;
    this.score = score;
    this.mQuestions = mQuestions;
    this.mChoices = mChoices;
    this.mCorrectAnswers = mCorrectAnswers;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.newquizrecyclerview_item, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    score.setText("Score: \u0020" + mScore);
    updateQuestion(holder, position);
    holder.answer.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        if (holder.answer.getText().toString().equals(correctanswer)) {
            mScore++;
            score.setText("Score: \u0020" + mScore);
            holder.answer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.roundgreen);
            updateQuestion(holder, position);
        } else {
            mScore--;
            score.setText("Score: \u0020" + mScore);
            holder.answer.setBackgroundResource(R.color.red);
            updateQuestion(holder, position);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {return mQuestions.length;}

private void updateQuestion(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(mQuestions));
    questions.setText(mQuestions[position]);
    holder.answer.setText(mChoices[position]);
    correctanswer = mCorrectAnswers[position];
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {holder.answer.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);}}, 500);
}

public void setClickListener(MainActivity mainActivity) {

}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView answer;

    public ViewHolder(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        answer = itemView.findViewById(R.id.info_text);
    }
}

}
